# Lightning Component error: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am new to Salesforce Lightning. Have been stuck with this error in various use cases. Trying a simple code to insert a contact. Getting this error every time. 
This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.

> Action failed: c:CreateContact$controller$saveContact [Cannot read
>   property 'get' of undefined] Failing descriptor:
>   {c:CreateContact$controller$saveContact}

**Apex**

```
public class ContactListController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static contact doSaveContact(contact con,string accid)

    {
        con.AccountId=accid;
        insert con;
        return con;
    }

}
```

**Component**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" controller="ContactListController" >

<aura:attribute name ="createContact" type="Contact" default="{                                                                  
     sobjectname:'contact',
     FirstName:'', 
     LastName:'',
     Email:'', 
     Phone:'' }"/>

<div class="slds-p-around_small">
        <lightning:input name ="FirstName" required="true" value="{!v.createContact.FirstName}" label="First Name"/>
        <lightning:input name ="LastName" required="true" value="{!v.createContact.LastName}" label="Last Name"/>
        <lightning:input name ="Email" required="true" value="{!v.createContact.Email}" label="Email"/>
        <lightning:input name ="phone" required="true" value="{!v.createContact.Phone}" label="phone"/>
        <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Save Contact" title="Save Contact" onclick="{!c.saveContact}"/>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**JS**

```
({
    saveContactInvoke : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action=component.get('c.doSaveContact');
        action.setParams({
            "con":component.get('v.createContact'),
            "accid":"0012v00002S8Y1hAAF"
        }
        );
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state=response.getState(); 
            if(state=="SUCCESS")
            {
                var responseValue=response.getReturnValue();
                console.log('responseValue' +responseValue);
            }
        });
          $A.enqueueAction(action,false);  
        }
})
```

Comment: On the onlcick event you are calling 'saveContact' , but in the controller you have defined 'saveContactInvoke'

Answer (score 2):

I think your function name is incorrect:

`saveContactInvoke : function(component, event, helper)`

Should be: 
`saveContact : function(component, event, helper)`